# Downloading python to macbook

Tags: python, macos, download

I learn a new Python book which means I need to download Python 3.6 to my Mac OS 10.14.4 - 
I don't find a link to download it - 
https://www.python.org/dwnloads/release/python-360/
It has only 10.6 version and above...

What can I do?
Thanks)

Comment: u can use the miniconda/Anaconda distribution

Comment: Did you look at the [Python downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/)?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use [Brew](https://brew.sh/#install) for installing your Python and all additional dependencies. 
Makes life much easier.
[Guide how to install python3 with Brew](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/)

Comment: `brew unlink python`



`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb`